# Textbox Style does not get applied to ItemsPresenter Textboxes

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, textblock

I tried to apply styling to all text boxes in the `ItemsPresenter` of a `HeaderedItemsControl`. It works flawless within the header of the control, but somehow not with its content.

Here is the `TextBlock` style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="StructuredViewText">
     <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2.5,5,10,2.5"/>
</Style>
```

Here is the the styling of the `HeaderedItemsControl`:

```
<Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header">
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StructuredViewText}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StructuredViewText}"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="2,0,0,0">
                            <ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StructuredViewText}"/>
                            </ItemsPresenter.Resources>
                        </ItemsPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel MaxWidth="300"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is how the `HeaderedItemsControl` is used:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:StructuredViewNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <!-- Beschreibung -->
        <HeaderedItemsControl Header="Beschreibung">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should assign `ItemTemplate` in your style [ItemTemplate MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. It's also not mentioned in the example for [HeaderedItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A headered itemscontrol is pretty much just an itemscontrol with a header. There will be an itemtemplate for the itemscontrol. Most developers will never have used one directly but will be much more familiar with menu and treeviews. Which have an otherwise somewhat mysterious Header property and of course also the child items within their respective items.

Comment: I just realised how you're using this. When you put a textblock in there directly as an item, you're not templating data into controls to give you that textblock, so the itemtemplate isn't going to be involved.

Comment: Mhh, do you any have any pointers on how I am supposed to be using this to be able to generate the behaviour I want, namely consistently styled textblocks? 
I know I could just apply the style to every `TextBlock` seperatly, but that seems noisy.

Comment: If your items are all `TextBlock`s then you would define the `ItemTemplate` as a TextBlock and then assign the style explicitly in that DataTemplate. This is due to the `DataTemplate` not being part of the `VisualTree` at compile time so Styles won't get applied out of the box.

Comment: The idea of a headereditemscontrol is that it's presenting multiple items in that itemspanel. You only seem to want the one item and that's a fixed textblock. A headeredcontentcontrol would be more appropriate if you specifically want a header. Just a grid with two rows looks like it'd get the job done though. It does rather depend what you're doing with this thing.

Comment: @Andy
This is just a simplified example. At other times there are more `TextBlock` presented in there. At other times I input `Grid`.
 
@XAMlMAX
Ahh, that makes sense! I will head into that direction. I sometimes also add `Grid` to the template, will this still work?

Comment: The way I would expect this sort of thing to work would be templating data into controls. Maybe you're actually doing that and the grid is one object type and the textblock another. I'd expect a template using datatype to differentiate and they could use basedon to apply this styling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't say I know how to do what you suggested just yet, but it seems like a good direction to put some further research into. Also, the part about `DataTemplate` not beeing a part of the visual tree and therefore not using styles is technically the answer, so if you want to write that up, I would accept it.

Comment: I didn't get notified about your comment for some reason! Any control you use inside of the `DataTemplate` will work, provided given Bindings are correct. Did you explicitly applied the Style for TextBlocks?

Comment: @XAMlMAX
Yes, I added it like this: [Changed Version](https://www.pastiebin.com/5acb37280ab15). The style does still not get applied though...
What is so strange to me, is that it works perfectly for the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your Template is not working in the current solution is because it is not part of the Visual Tree at compile time. Because of that the Style will not be applied. This will only work when you explicitly assign the style in your template like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:StructuredViewNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <!-- Beschreibung -->
        <HeaderedItemsControl Header="Beschreibung">
            <HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource StructuredViewText}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

After this the style will get evaluated when you run the app.
More info from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Hey Mate, sorry to bother you again, but if I add the text like in your example, the text simply disappears...

Comment: Hey, np. You might need to add `ContentPresenter` to the `DataTemplate` just like you set it the `Style` for `Template`.

Comment: @XAMIMAX In a way, I asked my experienced  WPF colleague if my general structure made sense at all. You know how it is, if things are to hard, chances are you have the wrong problem. He encouraged me to leave my very UI centric structure behind and organize it more data centric. As in, do not write templates that take grids, write templates, that take nodes, etc. So far I could delete half of my very bloated xaml file. I also reorganised my viewmodel to use composition instead of inheritance and slowly my visualisation becomes something I'm no longer kind of embarrassed of...

Comment: WPF has a steep learning curve. But it is something that we all went through. I am unsure what you mean by _templates take nodes instead of grids_, I hope you mean "use". Let us know when you finish and show your final code. I am sure more people would like to see what you have done.

Comment: Will do so for sure mate. Thanks for the positive reinforcement! Hope I will be knowledgeable enough at some point to return the favor.